# Issues with displaying certain array elements with a conditional in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a for loop to display all the elements in my array that are greater than 5. I am using an if-statement to determine the values greater than five, but when I run the code, I get values printed to the console that are both below and over five. I have tried creating variables to store the index values and tried using the && operator, but none of these have worked.

Here is the code for reference:

```
var myArray = [];
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));

console.log("Original: " + myArray);
console.log("Values greater than 5");

// the part I have issues with

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

if (myArray[i] > 5) {
console.log(i);
}

}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(myArray)` log after last `appendItem()`?

Comment: You're doing `console.log(i)`, which will log the current index. Instead, do `console.log(myArray[i])`.

Comment: You are logging i instead of myArray[i].

Comment: @Maciej Kasprak Thank you, I figured that out right after I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing `i` not the array element.
try

`console.log(myArray[i]);`